# Slow parallel code in Python compared to sequential version, why is it slower?

Tags: python

I have created two versions of a program to add the numbers of an array, one version uses concurrent programming and the other is sequential. The problem that I have is that I cannot make the parallel program to return a faster processing time. I am currently using Windows 8 and Python 3.x. My code is:

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor, ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed
import random
import time

def fun(v):
    s=0
    for i in range(0,len(v)):
        s=s+l[i]
    return s

def sumSeq(v):
    s=0
    start=time.time()
    for i in range(0,len(v)):
        s=s+v[i]
    start1=time.time()
    print ("time seq ",start1-start," sum = ",s)

def main():
    workers=4
    vector = [random.randint(1,101) for _ in range(1000000)]
    sumSeq(vector)
    dim=(int)(len(vector)/(workers*10))
    s=0
      
    chunks=(vector[k:k+dim] for k in range(0,len(vector),(int)(len(vector)/(workers*10))))
    start=time.time()
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=workers) as executor:
        futures=[executor.submit(fun,chunk) for chunk in chunks]
    
    start1=time.time()
    for future in as_completed(futures):
        s=s+future.result()
    
    print ("concurrent time ",start1-start," sum = ",s)
```

The problem is that I get the following answer:

```
time sec  0.048101186752319336  sum =  50998349
concurrent time  0.059157371520996094  sum =  50998349
```

I cannot make the concurrent version to runs faster, I have change the chunks size and the number of max workers to None, but nothing seems to work. What am I doing wrong? I have read that the problem could be the creation of the processes, so how can I fix that in a simple way?

Comment: Your code doesn't run as is. Can you please fix it? I get `dummyFun` not defined.

Comment: This is not a real workload, that's the main problem. There are truly many ways to "optimise" computation in Python, and parallelisation is not nearly the best. Here's my (old) overview of a few options: http://dimaqq.github.io/Number-Crunching/#/12/1

Comment: I agree with @DimaTisnek. This problem does not seem suitable for multiple processes. Also, there's the builtin `sum` for this :)

Comment: Also note that your program startup time dominates here, specifically `random` is slowish for large data. Your `vector = ...` takes ~0.8s on my machine, which is 20x longer than your reported computation time.

Answer (score 3):

A long-standing weakness of Python is that it can't run pure-Python code simultaneously in multiple threads; the keyword to search for is "GIL" or "global interpreter lock".

Ways around this:

- This only applies to CPU-heavy operations, like addition; I/O operations and the like can happily run in parallel. You can happily continue to run Python code in one thread while others are waiting for disk, network, database etc.
- This only applies to pure-Python code; several computation-heavy extension modules will release the GIL and let code in other threads run. Things like matrix operations in `numpy` or image operations can thus run in threads alongside a CPU-heavy Python thread.
- It applies to threads (`ThreadPoolExecutor`) specifically; the `ProcessPoolExecutor` will work the way you expect — but it's more isolated, so the program will spend more time marshalling and demarshalling the data and intermediate results.

I should also note that it looks like your example isn't really well suited to this test:

- It's too small; with a total time of 0.05s, a lot of that is going to be the setup and tear-down of the parallel run. In order to test this, you need at least several seconds, ideally many seconds or a couple of minutes.
- The sequential version visits the array in sequence; things like CPU cache are optimised for this sort of access. The parallel version will access the chunks at random, potentially causing cache evictions and the like.